# command prompt syntax

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Can anyone tell me what this command prompt does? I can't find it online.

```
echo ============================================================ > %name1%\%name2%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a prompt, it writes a line of `=` characters to the file with the name in the `name2` variable in the directory named by the `name1` variable.